# separating a weird formatted timestamp into an understandable date

Tags: php

I'm working with an XML document that is returning variables and for some reason in a xml return the timestamp is formatted like this... `20180606T110000` ... why anyone would format it like that makes no sense to me; however, its what I have to work with.  ITs formatted YYYYMMDD , the T is the split between date and time, HHMMSS.  ITs set up in a 24 Hour clock that I also need to convert to 12 hr clock with am/pm

**I need that formatted like 06/06/2018 11:00:00 AM.**

Is there a way to do that via a date format (I know how to use date() but I don't know how to bring in that timestamp the way its formatted) or even separating it out into

```
$year = xxxx 
$month = xx 
$day = $xx 
$Hour=xx 
etc. etc. etc.
```

if need be.

I've briefly looked at php's date create from format ( `date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009')` ) but dont fully understand how that works.

I've also thought about a split.  I've also looked at chunk_split and wordwrap but its not even amounts of characters so that would be complex to create.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is some ISO format but I don't recall which one right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you're working with is "XMLRPC (Compact)" format.  This is fully supported by PHP (you can see a list of supported formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)).  To get what you want, just use a combination of [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$timestring = "20180606T110000";

$timestamp = strtotime($timestring);

echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP DateTime to parse a datetime String with any format. Please view the Parameters format in the following link to understand how the "Ymd\THis" part works: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
<?php

$time = "20180606T110000";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd\THis", $time);

// 06/06/2018 11:00:00 AM.
echo $date->format("d/m/Y h:i:s A");
```